# Wordpress broken after vhosts setup

Tags: 404-error, xampp

I am working locally with wordpress installation using Xampp,
after using vhosts and changing wordpress options home and siteurl to wordpressurl.site , my website has been broken stylesheets and scripts are showing 404 errors ; also I can't access to wp-admin
Do anyone has an idea about this ?

I am using :

Windows 10
Xampp

Thanks in advance

Comment: it looks like you told XAMPP to use a domain but did you let your computer/Windows know? Did you update your hosts file? When you get a 404 what's the URL it's using and what happens when you go there yourself? Note that just because you changed the home/site url doesn't mean the URL changed everywhere else in the database too

Answer (score 0):

May be would be helpful for other person
in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://monurl.site');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://monurl.site');
```

It has take a time before changes take effect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).